# How to use filter in gapi.class.php?

Tags: php, api, google-analytics

I'm using [gapi.class.php](https://github.com/erebusnz/gapi-google-analytics-php-interface) to get data from google analytics api
Here is my example code

```
$filter = 'eventValue =~ 493';

$ga->requestReportData('00000000',array('eventLabel'),array('totalEvents','uniqueEvents','eventValue','avgEventValue','eventsPerSessionWithEvent'), 'totalEvents', $filter ,date("Y-m-d"), date("Y-m-d"));
```

I want to filter string with prefix is "Customer received code :" and suffix "493"

Example data :

```
Customer received code : 1493
Customer received code : 4933
Customer received code : 1234
Customer received code : 2334
Customer sent code : 555
Customer received code : 493
Customer sent code : 777
```

I would appreciate if you can provide any solution.

Thanks,